# python sqlite & bottle didn't response , running apache2/wsgi

Tags: python, apache, sqlite, mod-wsgi, bottle

I writing a web application with sign in/up functions , I'm using sqlite to implement it using python bottle.

when I used apache2  mod_wsgi to serving the appliciton the databases query didn't working , NO change in the Databases + No error messages appears !!.

also ,  when running the application Via bottle only , every things is works fine & OK.

see this code :

```
@bottle.get('/signup')
def sigup():
    pass_in =bottle.request.query.pass_in 

    email_in = bottle.request.query.email_in

    try : 
         if sqs.sign_up(email_in,pass_in) == "Done": 
            return(" Signed Up ")

    except Exception as e: 
         return(e) #NO Error Message returned
```

- The sqs.sign_up(email_in,pass_in) : Insert the password + email toe the sqlite Database.
- Im sure about the query statements for the sqlite script [sqs].

any help;

please Note : the problem only appeared when using apache2/mod_wsgi for running the python bottle script.

thanks in advance;

Comment: Check apache logs (on Linux `/var/logs/...`).  In `sigup()` print values on screen or write in file or log to see what variables you get and which part of code is executed.

Comment: I checked it , without getting any information .

Comment: then use `print` or write to log or `return` more information to get more inforamtion about varaibles and code. Maybe show  `sqs.sign_up` code.